# Officer Developer Tools VS Community 2015 won't install

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, installation

When trying to download ODTs for VS Comm 2015, the installer only is able to install one component before failing no matter how long it runs. Any advice why this keeps happening?

Comment: To find the root cause of this issue, you need to use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: How did you install the Office Developer Tools? Normally, after the initial installation of VS 2015, you can go to Control Panel—Programs and Features and right click the VS community 2015, Change-Modify, check the option “Microsoft Office Developer Tools” under Windows and Web Development to install, or directly download the latest standalone installer: https://aka.ms/officedevtoolsforvs2015 and before the installation, windows update is up-to-date and temporarily disable any antivirus, clean up the %temp% folder, then run the installer as administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  But I believe VS is just not recognizing my installation of Office.

Comment: does your issue is solved or not?

Comment: Yes.  I upgraded to Office 2010, but I have seen the option to choose the version of Office desired.  Maybe the VS used was a different version.

Comment: Does the installation of Microsoft Office Developer Tools is successful or not? After upgraded the office version, you can go to Control Panel-Programs and Features, right click the VS 2015 item and Change-Modify, select Windows and Web Development – Microsoft Office Developer Tools to install. Could you share the screenshot of File-New-Project-Installed-C#/VB-Office/SharePoint-Office Add-ins and check the templates that you can select.

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting VS over the past few days, I believe the real underlying problem is that VS is not recognizing my installation of Office Professional 2007.  Because Office Developer Tools is not in the installer to begin with. How do I correct this?

Comment: does your issue is solved or have you tried to upgrade your Office to a higher version, that can work with the VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Office 2007 is not a supported Office version to works with VS 2015, you can have a look at this: [Configuring a Computer to Develop Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242(v=vs.120).aspx). To create add-ins and customization for Office in VS 2015, it needs any suite edition of Office 2013 or Office 2010, except Click-to-Run versions of Office 2010 applications are not supported. The latest version of VS that supported on Office 2007 is VS 2010, you can know it through switch the VS edition in the above website page.

To get a better support and development in VS, you can think about upgrade to Office 365, check here: https://products.office.com/en-sg/download-office-2007

[image]